# How to cut multiple string from url in python

Tags: python, json, string

My code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBkHr.png)

So the output is giving the very first line of the `results` list.

My question is how to cut in each "url" element in one run to get the same result? Assume for loop would do?

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text.

Comment: See why [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: You should start by learning how to iterate over a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```py
cut = [results[i].split("/")[3].split("-")[0] for in range(len(results))]
```

This will give you a list of the cut result for each of the urls

Comment: Thanks, @UltimateFleet -that really answers my question. Pretty much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the values then:

```
list_ = ['https://ingatlan.com/xiii-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32942874',
'https://ingatlan.com/xiii-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32661461',
'https://ingatlan.com/xiv-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32879321',
'https://ingatlan.com/i-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32900903',
'https://ingatlan.com/vii-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32772342',
'https://ingatlan.com/viii-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32916928',
'https://ingatlan.com/vi-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32922203',
'https://ingatlan.com/xiv-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32947911',
'https://ingatlan.com/xix-ker/elado+lakas/panel-lakas/32961930']

print(*[e.split('/')[3].split('-')[0] for e in list_], sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
xiii
xiii
xiv
i
vii
viii
vi
xiv
xix
```